# CSS pseudo classes in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

This might apply to IE7 too, I'm not sure though.  I have the following CSS:

```
div#sidebar-right a.menu-item img:nth-child(1),
div#sidebar-right a.menu-item > *:first-child {
    position: relative;
    left: 11px;
    top: 37px;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(6deg);

    -webkit-transition-property: top, opacity, -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s, 0.3s, 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, linear, ease-in;

    -moz-transition-property: top, opacity, -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s, 0.3s, 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: linear, linear, ease-in;
}

div#sidebar-right a.menu-item:hover img:nth-child(1),
div#sidebar-right a.menu-item:hover > *:first-child {
    top: -6px;
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

div#sidebar-right a.menu-item img:nth-child(2),
div#sidebar-right a.menu-item > *:first-child + * {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 11;
    top: -63px;
}

div#sidebar-right a.menu-item.home-menu:hover img:nth-child(2),
div#sidebar-right a.menu-item.home-menu:hover > *:first-child + * {
    top: -100px;
}

div#sidebar-right a.menu-item.code-menu:hover img:nth-child(2),
div#sidebar-right a.menu-item.code-menu:hover > *:first-child + * {
    top: -97px;
}

div#sidebar-right a.menu-item.game-menu:hover img:nth-child(2),
div#sidebar-right a.menu-item.game-menu:hover > *:first-child + * {
    top: -101px;
}

div#sidebar-right a.menu-item.sports-menu:hover img:nth-child(2),
div#sidebar-right a.menu-item.sports-menu:hover > *:first-child + * {
    top: -98px;
}

div#sidebar-right a.menu-item.the-nation-menu:hover img:nth-child(2),
div#sidebar-right a.menu-item.the-nation-menu:hover > *:first-child + * {
    top: -98px;
}
```

For some reason this CSS is not being picked up in IE8 at all.  I understand that nth-child is not supported in IE8, but first-child is and that's also listed as a rule here.  Any thoughts?  What's really puzzling is that the rule isn't just not being applied, it's just not showing up.  If you look at the Developer Tools view under the CSS tab, you can literally scroll through the entire thing and not see any of these rules in there.  Very confusing.

Comment: `:nth-child()` and `:first-child` are pseudo-classes, not pseudo-elements. IE7 does not support any CSS2 pseudo-elements, but it does support some CSS2 pseudo-classes like `:first-child`. It's a subtle but important difference :)

Comment: Thanks for the grammar analysis.  I actually knew that but just mind-farted when writing the subject.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you misunderstood how selector parsing works. IE8 sees selector of the form `something_invalid, something_valid` which means it should ignore the entire selector and not apply the properties. I'll give you another example - imagine you specify selector like `div, p:foo-bar { /* properties */ }`. Even if the `div` selector is completely valid, the declaration is dropped because of the unrecognized pseudoclass `foo-bar`. Browsers always check if the *entire* selector is valid; there's nothing special when using comma in the selector.

The solution is simple - just remove the `nth-child` part of selectors; your notation with `first-child` will match the desired elements in all browsers.

Comment: +1 fantastic answer.  I never realized that.  This is a great lesson and a really easy pitfall for noobs like myself.  Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

try `a.menu-item.home-menu:hover *` instead of `a.menu-item.home-menu:hover > *:first-child + *`

Comment: forget to mention for opacity you need to use filter: and -ms-filter

Comment: and what about changing * to img? (...:hover > img + img)

Comment: I intentionally left the filter out.  In Chrome and Firefox the menu items perform an animation on hover, but since animating is a royal pain in IE I just left out the animation part.  The opacity element was only necessary for the animation, so I omitted it.